# Ruby on Rails model associations nubie question

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

dear developers I have some problems with Rails models
Here is my sql tables

```
  create_table "areas", :primary_key => "ndc", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "townname", :limit => 256, :null => false
  end

  create_table "books", :primary_key => "ndc", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "booked", :null => false
    t.integer "free",   :null => false
  end



class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "ndc"
  has_one :area, :foreign_key => 'ndc'
end

class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key = "ndc"
    belongs_to :book , :foreign_key => 'ndc'
end
```

in controller I have such code

```
   @books = Book.paginate :page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 10
     @books.each do |booking|
      p booking.area
      p booking

     end
```

In production mode doesn't work, booking.area is nil object. what it can be ?

Area becames nil if   config.cache_classes = true

so booking.area generates such queries
if cashe_classes = true
SELECT `areas`.* FROM `areas` WHERE (`areas`.ndc = NULL) LIMIT 1
but without cashing classes
 SELECT `areas`.* FROM `areas` WHERE (`areas`.ndc = 30) LIMIT 1

FIXED by removing  belongs_to :book , :foreign_key => 'ndc' from area class.

Comment: I added  self.primary_key = "ndc" to Book class and association seems to be working now. Thank you

Comment: Yes, any time you use a name other than "id" for your primary key field, you must insert a statement in your ActiveRecord class specifying that primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `areas` table needs a `book_id` integer field to match against the books table's primary key.

Comment: thnks , in this case books must have area_id , but if not , I can't use association if I ovveride foreign_key?

Comment: You can do that, but then the has_one statement should be in your Area class and the belongs_to should be in your Book class (the class with the belongs_to statement is expected to have the XXX_id field referencing the has_one class). Also, you may actually want the Areas class to have a has_many statement, not a has_one statement -- assuming that multiple books can belong to an area?

Comment: I understood that , thnks. Question is next:   is  there no  way to associate them  by ndc field without creating additional column ??

Comment: Do you mean that if a book's ndc is 4, it should be matched up with the area whose ndc is 4? If that's the case, why have two separate tables?

Comment: because i have 5k records in area table and only few records in book table, but all area table is used in other logic